# Jquery dialog not RUN on PHP foreach

Tags: php, jquery, user-interface

have this following code:

```
 <?php foreach ($arr_person as $new_person):?>

<div id= "demo">
<div id= "dialog">
</div>
<input type="button" id="botton" name="botton">
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In the press button run a dialog!
more, the code load everything buttons.

Comment: please be more explicit! i know it's hard but give it a try :)

Answer (score 4):

This can't ever work with jquery, because you **CAN'T** have multiple elements with same `id` attribute.

change all same `id`s to classes and also change them in jQuery (`#` to `.`) and it should work